# jquery: resizing image problems in ie?

Tags: jquery, image, width

hey guys,
my ie source code of an image says this:

```
<img width="1500" src="something.jpg" style="width:1265px" alt="something"/>
```

this means the image is actually 1500px wide and i'm dynamically resizing it to 1265px with jquery:

this is the code i'm using:

```
                    $(this).removeAttr('height');
                    $(this).width(bw);
```

in some version of ie this means it doesn't actually show an image, probably due to the fact that there is a different width than the style attribute tells it to have.

I'm guessing $(this).width is transformed to style="width:value" right?
how can i directly modify the width-attribute of the image dynamically width jquery?

regards matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify attributes with attr()

```
$(this).attr('width','1265');
```

or

```
$(this).attr({'width':'1265'});
```

if you want to set the style use css()

```
$(this).css('width','1265px');
```

or

```
$(this).css({'width':'1265px'});
```

Comment: Andy is right, you don't alter the width of the image while using the jQuery .width property. Instead you'll use jQuery's CSS or attr commands to alter its dimensions.